# How to Solving a nonlinear PDE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I wish to solve the following PDE

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \lvert \nabla u \rvert^{p-2} \text{div} \left( \dfrac{\nabla u}{\lvert \nabla u \rvert^{p} }\right)$$

We search for a self-similarity solution, the general form of which is as follows

$$u(x,y,t) = f \left( \xi \right), \text{ with } \xi = \dfrac{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{n}}{a (t)}$$

from which we obtain

$$\frac{-\alpha}{1-p} \xi^{2} = \left[ \left( \frac{1}{2n (1-p)} + \frac{2n-1}{2n} \right) \left( \dfrac{df}{d \xi} \right)^{-2} + \xi \left( \dfrac{df}{d \xi} \right)^{-3} \dfrac{d^{2}f}{d \xi^{2}} \right]$$

Now, I am very confused on how to solve the above equation and find the exact solution of $f(\xi)$, thereby finding the exact solution of $u(x,y,t)$. So my question is, does anyone know how to solve this ordinary differential equation?

Comment: One approach for an approximate solution may be the method of dominant balance. You would multiply through by $(df/d\xi)^3$ and neglect the nonlinear term, then solve the second order ODE

Comment: @mattos Thanks for your candid answer, I have a note about Setting $\dfrac{df}{d\xi }=\xi ^{\gamma }h$, do $f^{\prime \prime }=\xi ^{\gamma }h^{\prime }$ ? So we get this EDO: $\xi ^{1+\gamma }h^{\prime }+c_{1}\left( n,p\right) \xi ^{\gamma}h=c_{2}\left( \alpha ,p\right) \xi ^{2+3\gamma }h^{3}$

Comment: Sorry, I removed an intermediate step before posting to simplify my comment and made a mistake meaning everything that followed was wrong. Make the transformation as before $f' = \xi^{\gamma} h$ to get $$\gamma \xi^{\gamma} h + \xi^{\gamma+1}h' + c_{1} \xi^{\gamma} h = c_{2} \xi^{2+3\gamma} h^{3}$$ Take $\gamma = -c_{1}$ and divide through by $\xi^{\gamma+1}$ to get $$h' = c_{2} \xi^{1+2\gamma} h^{3}$$ which is separable.